# How to traverse dynamic nested json in c# recursively

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-core

If dataGeneratorType is range then the value can be anything between dataGeneratorStart and dataGeneratorEnd. If dataGeneratorType is array with no length property then the value will be one value randomly selected from the array, otherwise it be two randomly selected values that equals to the length. If it is the object (which can be more nested) then it will again follow the above logic. But this is where it gets tricky for me. Is there any dynamic way to solve the problem in C#.

Input payload json

```
{
    "temperature": {
        "type": "int",
        "dataGeneratorType": "range",
        "dataGeneratorStart": -5,
        "dataGeneratorEnd": 55
    },
    "salesAmount": {
        "type": "float",
        "dataGeneratorType": "array",
        "dataGeneratorArray": [
            0.51,
            13.33,
            20.01,
            1.54
        ]
    },
    "city": {
        "type": "string",
        "dataGeneratorType": "array",
        "dataGeneratorArray": [
            "UK",
            "Iceland",
            "Portugal",
            "Spain"
        ]
    },
    "relatedTags": {
        "type": "array",
        "dataGeneratorType": "array",
        "dataGeneratorArray": [
            "Sport",
            "Hardware",
            "Cycling",
            "Magazines"
        ],
        "length": 2
    },
    "salesDetail": {
        "type": "object",
        "dataGeneratorType": "object",
        "dataGeneratorValue": {
            "VAT": {
                "type": "float",
                "dataGeneratorType": "range",
                "dataGeneratorStart": 0.0,
                "dataGeneratorEnd": 20.0
            },
            "discountAmount": {
                "type": "float",
                "dataGeneratorType": "array",
                "dataGeneratorArray": [
                    0.10,
                    0.15,
                    0.20
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To output json:

```
{
    "temperature": 20,
    "salesAmount": 20.01,
    "city": "Iceland",
    "relatedTags": [
        "Sport",
        "Cycling"
    ],
    "salesDetails": {
        "VAT": 15.0,
        "discount": 0.1
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post an attempt.

Comment: Why don't you just create a model to convert your JSON to C# objects first... and then try to do the logic?

Comment: Key name might change. It can be even more nested.

Comment: So? If you have a property that it is for example the same type as the root object in the root object it can be as nested as you want...

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro you can have object within object

Comment: @Train my currently implementation static but i'm looking for a dynamic approach if the json grows

Comment: Ok I'll give you my attempt at an answer soon.

Comment: you can have objectes that have properties of the same type as the object...

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: //Recursive function call
                    Traverse(nestedItem.Value)//pass in as a json string
The recursive call is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
static string TransformJson(string inputPayload)
{
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(inputPayload);
    var manipulatedObj = obj.DeepClone();
    foreach (var child in obj)
    {
        var key = child.Key;
        var t = child.Value["type"];
        JToken genType;
        if (!((JObject)child.Value).TryGetValue("dataGeneratorType", out genType))
        {
            continue; // genType is not found so, continue with next object.
        }

        var str = genType.Type == JTokenType.String ? genType.ToString().ToLower() : null;
        switch (str)
        {
            case "range":
                var r = new Random();
                if (((string)t).ToLower() == "float")
                {
                    var s = (float)child.Value["dataGeneratorStart"];
                    var e = (float)child.Value["dataGeneratorEnd"];
                    manipulatedObj[key] = r.NextDouble() * e;
                }
                else
                {
                    var s = (int)child.Value["dataGeneratorStart"];
                    var e = (int)child.Value["dataGeneratorEnd"];
                    manipulatedObj[key] = r.Next(s, e);
                }

                break;
            case "array":
                var arr = child.Value["dataGeneratorArray"];
                JToken lengthToken;
                if (!((JObject)child.Value).TryGetValue("length", out lengthToken))
                {
                    lengthToken = 2.ToString();
                }

                if ((string)t != "array")
                {
                    manipulatedObj[key] = arr.OrderBy(a => a).LastOrDefault();
                }
                else
                {
                    var count = arr.Count() >= (int)lengthToken ? (int)lengthToken : arr.Count();
                    var item = new JArray();
                    foreach (var m in Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => arr[i]))
                    {
                        item.Add(m);
                    }

                    manipulatedObj[key] = item;
                }

                break;
            case "object":
                var transformJson = TransformJson(child.Value["dataGeneratorValue"].ToString());
                manipulatedObj[key] = JObject.Parse(transformJson);
                break;
            default:
                manipulatedObj[key] = child.Value["dataGeneratorValue"];
                break;
        }
    }

    return manipulatedObj.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
}
```

And use it as below:

```
var serializeObject =   @"{""temperature"":{""type"":""int"",""dataGeneratorType"":""range"",""dataGeneratorStart"":-5,""dataGeneratorEnd"":55},""salesAmount"":{""type"":""float"",""dataGeneratorType"":""array"",""dataGeneratorArray"":[0.51,13.33,20.01,1.54]},""relatedTags"":{""type"":""array"",""dataGeneratorType"":""array"",""dataGeneratorArray"":[""Sport"",""Hardware"",""Cycling"",""Magazines""],""length"":2},""salesDetail"":{""type"":""object"",""dataGeneratorType"":""object"",""dataGeneratorValue"":{""VAT"":{""type"":""float"",""dataGeneratorType"":""range"",""dataGeneratorStart"":0.0,""dataGeneratorEnd"":20.0},""discountAmount"":{""type"":""float"",""dataGeneratorType"":""array"",""dataGeneratorArray"":[0.1,0.15,0.2]}}}}";
Console.WriteLine(serializeObject);
var outputJson = TransformJson(serializeObject);
Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine + "Modified Json = " + System.Environment.NewLine);
Console.WriteLine(outputJson);
```

I just added everything in one function but you can split into multiple functions and/or classes to make unit testing easier.

Here is the [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ePC9ps).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jist of the logic for your problem. To parse nested json you have to use a recursive statement and do the processing for each layer.

```
public Void Traverse(string myJsonString){

        var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

        foreach (var item in jObj)
        {
            if(item.Value["dataGeneratorType"].ToString().Equals("range")){
                Console.WriteLine("Do some logic");
            }
            else if(item.Value["dataGeneratorType"].ToString().Equals("array")){

                if(item.Value["length"] != null){
                    Console.WriteLine("Length is present do more logic");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No length property present do more logic");

                }


            }
            else if(item.Value["dataGeneratorType"].ToString().Equals("object")){

                Console.WriteLine("It's an object");
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value["dataGeneratorValue"]);

                foreach (var nestedItem in item.Value["dataGeneratorValue"]){
                    Console.WriteLine("Nested Item");
                    Console.WriteLine(nestedItem);
                    //Recursive function call
                    Traverse(nestedItem.Value)//pass in as a json string
                }


            }


        }

    }
}
```